# How to efficiently parse multiple data with json?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have Django REST framework app

When for example I make POST book with title `Hobbit`

I want to fetch data into database but problem

https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=Hobbit

I got many many book with this title and I only need specific data like:

my models:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=249,
        null=True)
    autors = models.CharField(
        max_length=500,
        null=True)
    published_date = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        blank=True)
    categories = models.CharField(
        max_length=500,
        null=True)
    average_rating = models.PositiveBigIntegerField(
        blank=True)
    ratings_count = models.PositiveBigIntegerField(
        null=True)
    thumbnail = models.CharField(
        max_length=300,
        null=True)
```

What best practise to parse all this data and save into database ?

I already know how with `requests` get to the data I need.

Problem is how effectively use `drf` and implement this feature in the best way .

gp

Comment: Your answer is `Serializer`. Please read the `Serializer` section on DRF's site.

Comment: @ÇağatayBarın Thanks for a suggestion, could you specify where I have to look?

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the names and types in the response are not exactly the same than in your model, you will need to do a little bit of custom mapping.
Then you have two choices to create your objects, either calling `Book.objects.create()` or `serializer.save()`

Most of the time, you will just want to stick to serializers.

```py
import requests
import json
from book.models import Book
from book.serializers import BookSerializer

items = json.loads(requests.get("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=Hobbit").content).get('items')

for book in items:
    mapping = {
        'title': book['volumeInfo']['title'],
        'autors': ','.join(book['volumeInfo']['authors']),
        ...
    }

    # Via a serializer
    serializer = BookSerializer(**mapping)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        instance = serializer.save()

    # Via Django ORM
    instance = Book.objects.create(**mapping)
```

You can use a ModelSerializer ([see here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer)), that would look like this :

```py
from rest_framework import serializers

class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ['title', 'autors', 'published_date', ...] # or '__all__' if you want them all
```

Comment: thanks, I have to override creating method??

Comment: Not necessarily, the create method is inherited from the `ModelSerializer` class.
It is called with validated_data, that's why you have to call `serializer.is_valid()` before `serailizer.save()`, else you have an error. 
That means you must pass "clean" params to the serializer when initializing it, that's what I do in the dictionary I called _mapping_.